# How to extract a fragment of an element in an existing array to generate a new array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array :

```
string[] arr = new string[2]
arr[0] = "a=01"
arr[1] = "b=02"
```

How can I take those number out and make  a new array to store them? What I am expecting is :

```
int [] newArr = new int[2]
```

Inside newArr, there are 2 elements, one is '01' and the other one is '02' which both from arr.

Comment: `String.Substring`

Comment: If these strings are always in the format of [letters][space][numbers], you can also use `String.Split` on spaces, and use the second element (index 1) of the resulting array.

Comment: Will it always be one character, equals sign, then a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way besides `Substring` to get the desired result is to use `String.Split` on the `=` character. This is assuming the string will always have the format of letters and numbers, separated by a `=`, with no other `=` characters in the input string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    // Split the array item on the `=` character.
    // This results in an array of two items ("a" and "01" for the first item)
    var tmp = arr[i].Split('=');

    // If there are fewer than 2 items in the array, there was not a =
    // character to split on, so continue to the next item.
    if (tmp.Length < 2) 
    {
        continue;
    }

    // Try to parse the second item in the tmp array (which is the number
    // in the provided example input) as an Int32.
    int num;
    if (Int32.TryParse(tmp[1], out num))
    {
        // If the parse is succesful, assign the int to the corresponding
        // index of the new array.
        newArr[i] = num;
    }
}
```

This can be shortened in a lambda expression like the other answer like so:

```
var newArr = arr.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x.Split('=')[1])).ToArray();
```

Though doing it with `Int32.Parse` can result in an exception if the provided string is not an integer. This also assumes that there is a `=` character, with only numbers to the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a substring and then parse as int.

```
var newArr = arr.Select(x=>Int32.Parse(x.Substring(2))).ToArray();
```

Comment: what if it's possible for a string such as "ab 01"?

Comment: thats not what the question has

Comment: whats x for? Also I edited my question, I missed = in my first array's element

Comment: @CZA Its a lambda expression.  You will see this a lot with Linq.  [Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Comment: @pm100 Should be `=>`, not `->`.

Comment: @CZA The `=>` operator is called the lambda operator, but I find it helps if I read it in my head as "becomes". So "arr dot select x becomes ..."

Comment: @cza x is a variable that holds the current array element as linq is looping through the array. It could be called anything, you need it because you need a reference to the current element in order to split it up/parse it as an int

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have noted, it's quite compact to use linq. PM100 wrote:

```
var newArr = arr.Select(x=>Int32.Parse(x.Substring(2))).ToArray();
```

You asked what x was.. that linq statement there is conceptually the equivalent of something like:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
foreach(string x in arr)
  nums.Add(Int32.Parse(x.Substring(2);
var newArr = nums.ToArray();
```

It's not exactly the same, internally linq probably doesn't use a List, but it embodies the same concept - for each element (called x) in the string array, cut the start off it, parse the result as an int, add it to a collection, convert the collection to an array

Sometimes I think linq is overused; here probably efficiencies could be gained by directly declaring an int array the size of the string one and filling it directly, rather than adding to a List or other collection, that is later turned into an int array. Proponents of either style could easily be found; linq is compact and makes relatively trivial work of more long hand constructs such as loops within loops within loops. Though not necessarily easy to work out for those unfamiliar with how to read it it does bring a certain self documenting aspect to code because it uses English words like Any, Where, Distinct and these more quickly convey a concept than does looking at a loop code that exits early when a test returns true (Any) or builds a dictionary/hashset from all elements and returns it (Distinct)